# What type of plastic water supply pipe do I have in my crawlspace?

Tags: water, pipe, pex

The hot water line under my crawl space cracked so I am trying to replace myself. The existing pipe is grey,  has CTS 3/4" 7/8 O.D. print and connected with brass ring clamps and fittings.  So I bought sharkbite pex pipe 3/4" from Lowe's and after removing the existing pipe I found out the new one is thicker and can't slide onto the existing fittings.  The Lowe's one has a thickness of around 3.5/32 in and the existing one is around 2.5/32" (0.078).where can I buy the same thickness of the existing one or if there something I can do,  Please help.  Need to DIY to save money.[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you get us a photo of more of the printing on the pipe?

Comment: Hi,  I added one more photo.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is actually CTS (copper tube size) CPVC. It is smaller and thinner than the normal sized PVC. If it has cracked here it will likely crack else where so If you can get to it, I would recommend replacing the entire run with one piece of PEX. And making the end connections in an accessible space.

Comment: Thank you Dan. If I use cats cvpc,  can I use copper clamps as those existing ones shown to connect them?  Thanks.

Comment: cpvc is still legal to use but now that it has been in use for quite a while we know that it has a strong tendency to become brittle and prone to cracking and rupturing.  If you are replacing any pipe at all, replace it with pex.

Comment: With PEX there are multiple ways to do the connections.  Here in Portland, the Wirsbo expansion ring is the most popular professional done connection.  Though for quick fixes shops that don't want to invest in the expensive expansion tools for wirsbo tend to the use the stainless clamp.  That is one inexpensive too that will crimp all sizes of clamps.  All the other sizes require a different die or expansion head/tool for the different pipe sizes and isn't something diy'er should probably invest in.  So, I should suggest going with the stainless crimp rings.

Comment: Look for the video titled "comparing pex connections" here (https://www.supplyhouse.com/resources/videos).  It is a good quick introduction to the different kind of pex connections much better than I can type in this limited comments.